# PHP + SQL SERVER 2005: правильное преобразование в дату?

Tags: php, sql-server

Добрый день.

В PHP скрипте делаю запрос к SQL сервер с фильтрацией по дате:

```
$start_date = 2011-09-20 00:00:00.000
$now_date = 2011-09-20 17:45:16.999

AND moment >= CAST('$start_date' AS datetime2)
AND moment <= CAST('$now_date' AS datetime2)
```

Но сервер не распознаёт преобразование строки в дату: Type date is not a defined system type.

Если

```
AND moment >= CONVERT (datetime, '2011-09-20 00:00:00.000', 21) 
AND moment >= CONVERT (datetime, '2011-09-20 18:10:02.000', 21)
```

В ответ получаю ничего, т.е. условия фильтрации не выполняются. Пытался использовать CONVERT (datetime, '2011-09-20 18:10:02.000', 21) опять же пустота в ответ.

Не работает на SQL Server 2005 Express.

Как правильно переводить строку в дату на 2005-м. На 2008-м все вышеприведённые примеры работают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Server Helper - Tips and Tricks - Date Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, работает:

    AND moment >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), '$start_date', 121)
    AND moment <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), '$now_date', 121)

Так тоже работает:

    AND moment >= CONVERT (datetime, '2011-09-20 00:00:00.000', 21) 
    AND moment <= CONVERT (datetime, '2011-09-20 18:10:02.000', 21)

Я там допустил ошибку в операторе сравнение "<="